# Fill data into the recv-Buffer locally

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming, winsock

I hook into the `send` and `recv` functions in Windows. In some situations I modify the data that's going to be sent and read. In the `send` function, this is easy. I hook into the function, modify the source buffer and then pass it to the original function. But for the `recv` function, this is more complicated. When I've called the original `recv` function and I'm going to decide to add more data, I need to push data into the local queue so that the next call of `recv` would return those bytes. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I didn't understand, you want to create queue before working socket?then deliver to socket?

Comment: I want to insert data into the local recv buffer. It's like I'm sending data from the remote partner which then will be put into the recv buffer. So what I want to do: faking that data has been received from the remote partner.

Comment: So you need code before socket, before recv, use lower `layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter method should call recv() and then add your data to the end of the buffer, adjust the read count returned, and return it. No need to 'push data into the local queue'.

Comment: Likely to result in buffer overrun.

Comment: Yeah, Martin James is right. It is not that easy, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Well obviously you can only put as much data into the buffer as will fit. You must have some external source of the extra data you want recv() to return, and you can only use as much of that at a time as will fit. I didn't think I needed to elaborate every trivial detail.

Comment: It's not that trivial.  If the user code asks for a 256 byte read to go into a 256-byte buffer, the hook code reads 256 bytes and then decides that more data needs to be added in, there is more data available than will fit in the user buffer.  The extra data has to be buffered somewhere in an extra queue buffer associated with the socket/handle so that it can be returned on the next read() call.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your fake data into the address corresponding to the incoming parameter buff of recv the next time the client gets data from the real server, and return the length of your fake data